# What was the first coin to offer "reflex" and auto-adding liquidity?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ico

## Who was first?

I see these features being forked on a massive scale.

I would like to know who was first and where to find GitHub repo (ideally with tests) so I can play with it.

#### SafeMoon

SafeMoon maybe? Massively successful...

- https://safemoon.net/
- https://bscscan.com/address/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3#code

[image]

#### Pangea

I see these features being recreated in other places:

- https://pangeamovement.com/pages/pangea-coin
- https://www.bscscan.com/address/0x123f92226c626adc919ad122d6cc3c20a6c25666#code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reflect.finance (RFI) contract was deployed ~6 months ago to the Ethereum mainnet, in [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x55e6dbc5e129c818f44f6df24c3d7e415e1d8cbbf2558fdcd9e44dda3d28d0e1) transaction.

That predates both of your examples by a long way (Safemoon [77 days ago](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x08278405d40de452ff8d2862a2937d9bc54a43c26a3dff735d56de77b0aca609), and Pangea [12 days ago](https://www.bscscan.com/tx/0x7a27b933efe3ec3e930bb750021e465f19661bca46e979c4230b040ef1407ee6)).

Here's the main reflect.finance contract - [`REFLECT.sol`](https://github.com/reflectfinance/reflect-contracts/blob/main/contracts/REFLECT.sol)

You'll notice that SafeMoon has "borrowed" some of their ideas...

Comment: I don't think is a good thing you go back to a genesis idea. Every new copy has improvements that make the concept better.

Comment: That might be true. But the question asked who was first :-)

Comment: You're right... ;-) I don't even know what  "reflection" is ....

Comment: Awesome. @RichardHorrocks bonus question - which contract is currently the most advanced? Just like Goose (yield farm) clones adding more and more features :)

Comment: Good question :-) I'm not sure. The space moves so quickly, and in so many different directions that it's hard to keep up... !